# Is this a PHP OO bug?

Tags: php, oop

Given the following example:

```
<?php

class Model
{

    private $data = [];

    public function __set($property, $value)
    {   
        $this->data[$property] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        if(isset($this->data[$property]))
        {
            return $this->data[$property];
        }
        throw new Exception("Error trying to access undefined data");
    }

    public static function all()
    {
        // returns all models
    }

    public function save()
    {
        // save something to database 
    }
}
```

And this class:

```
class Person extends Model 
{
    protected $name;

    public static function migrateNamesToUppercase()
    {   
        foreach(self::all() as $person)
        {
            $person->name = strtoupper($person->name);
            $person->save();
        }
    }

}
```

- Inside static method "Person::migrateNamesToUppercase" `$person->name` is null.
- Outside static method "Person::migrateNamesToUppercase" `(new Person())->name` throws the expected exception.

When the class instance lives inside a static method of the same class PHP just assumes it has access to a protected property and neither `__get` or `__set` is executed! Sadly, same thing happens to private properties.

My question is: Shouldn't the behavior of the instances be the same in both contexts? Is this a known bug or just a failed PHP OO implementation?

- I googled about it and found nothing

Comment: Are you running PHP 5.4 or 5.5, they are different versions

Comment: It happens in both versions. I'm not sure about 5.3

Comment: There's nothing object oriented about all those `static` methods ...

Comment: Just noticed this: `public function $data = [];`. Specifically the `function` part. Don't know if this is the issue.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn wrong code. It's correct now.

Comment: is `property` vs `propery` in your getter method also wrong code? could you actually provide a working example?

Comment: Notice you have a typo here `$this->data[$propery]` and again below

Comment: Do you Have a pic of the person? I really would like to meet her considering she `is a` model (*cough* [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) *cough*)

Comment: I don't understand your code and your question. It has both too much code which is not relevant and does not have the code actually testing your issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method accessing protected property of another object of the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778675/method-accessing-protected-property-of-another-object-of-the-same-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `__get()` is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

[See the PHP manual for details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)

It's working as defined. `$name` is accessible from the object so it does not use the method. If `$name` were private and defined in the parent class it would be inaccessible and so would use the method.

Comment: My point is that it should not. The instance has a protected property, and inside the static method this property behaves like public. Does not look right to me so I think it can be a bug or failed implementation.

Comment: This is correct. You can just call `$this->__get('varname')` when trying to access internal properties and there is additional processing that might be necessary.

Comment: @marcioAlmada Fundamentally you are making a design decision when you put a static method inside another class. I think it's perfectly reasonable behaviour given the definition of `__get()` [which you are using in a hilariously silly fashion anyway]

Comment: "Inside static method "Person::migrateNamesToUppercase" $person->name is null." Well why wouldn't it be? You've specifically added `protected $name;` so it's accessible in any methods in the class definition. `__get` is only called for properties not specifically and publicly defined in a class. Inside that class private/protected properties are accessible so `__get` should not be called.

Comment: @marcioAlmada why should it not? How can a class not have access to its own protected properties, even from static methods? I think Java works this way too!

Comment: So shouldn't I had to call `$person->__get('varname')` too? So if I want to break object property permissions I just have to create a static method and set anything I want?

Comment: @marcioAlmada you can do that also with normal instance methods!

Comment: That's not the case. You are inside that class definition, why wouldn't you be able to set private/protected properties?

Comment: Just because an instance is inside a static method of it's own class doesn't mean all the properties that belongs to that instance should be accessible. This is crazy.

Comment: Only a method (static or otherwise) inside the class will have this behaviour. Your mistake is to think static and non-static methods are totally different.

Comment: What if I had a property that should never be set after construct?Can I change it if my instance is inside a static method?

Comment: This has been discussed before. Java does the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778675/method-accessing-protected-property-of-another-object-of-the-same-class

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv, that's the kind of reference I was looking for.

Comment: @marcioAlmada If the property is private only a method inside the class that defines it can change it. This is basic OOP. Your mistake is to forget static methods are inside the class.

Comment: @marcioAlmada: if you really want to "break object property permissions", you can modify inaccessible properties using Reflection.